# Can't hide serie if using boost mode with firefox

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having trouble hidding series using boost mode with firefox, hiding the series doesn't work.

Here is a jsfiddle to test https://jsfiddle.net/q3us4m0w/, it works with Chrome but not Firefox

Here I hide all series except one all is working properly :
[image: Here I hide all series except one]

Now I click to show another serie, it works :
[image: Now I click to show another serie]

And now I want to hide the serie I just show and it doesn't work :
[image: And now I want to hide the serie I just show and it doesn't work]

The serie Onduleur 11 is still visible but there is no tooltip which seems normal because we ask to not showing the serie.

When I click on a serie I hide all series using mySerie.setVisible(true or false,false);
And then I redraw the chart using mychart.redraw().

Why does it work with Chrome and not Firefox ? I have 0 error or warning in the js console I don't know what is going on ..

Here I hide all series and they are still displayed, there is no tooltip and also no Y legend which seems logic because all series are set not visibled

[image]

I have the same behavior if I set serie.setVisible(false,false) manually all series and chart.redraw() so i don't think the problem is with my implementation.

I am using the last version v10.0.0, I also tried with the v9

I found something strange in the html there is many `<image class="highcharts-boost-canvas">` in the `<g class="highcharts-series-group">`

One with the previous display and another with the current display

the href of the previous display is empty but still visible.

[image]

If I remove the empty href `<image>` it works

[image]

Deleting images with empty href is not correct but I found a work around by setting display:none and revert the property on these images to refresh them

Comment: Could you prepare a demo with your simplified case, I need to look at your code to check.

Comment: Ok I will try, deleting images with empty href is not correct but I found a work around by setting display:none and revert the property on these images to refresh them

Comment: @SebastianHajdus here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q3us4m0w/, it works with chrome but not firefox

Comment: I checked on Version 98.0.2 (64-bit) Firefox, your example behaviors the same on both browsers also [this](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jb96ye58/1/), could you check it?

Comment: @SebastianHajdus yes same problem, I created an issue here https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17182 don't know if my english is good enough I am using firefox 99.0.1 on mac os

Comment: Ok, I replicated this, it's looks like a bug, thanks for reporting.